# How to render Form-sets out of forms.ModelForm [model is connected to User using a ForeignKey]

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model called Ans as

```
class Ans(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

and a Form called AnswerForm

```
class AnsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ans
        fields = ('ans',)
        labels = {
            "ans": ''
        }
        help_texts = {
            'ans': 'Click ADD or press Enter to add'
        }
```

I want users to add multiple answers to the question. I have done  a not so very exciting way around on this. What I do is that I render the form every time no matter what and then I have provided a link to Proceed so that users can go to next page. It does not look good. Can Somebody please tell me how can I use `FormSets` on this so that when user press the submit button, he can be directed to the link instead of re rendering the form again again.

**NOTE- When my form re-renders, it shows the old value as initial input. Can some one help me on this one too about how to clear that field when the form re renders**